# Association [setting relationships] in wp7 mango DB

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

How i can achieve relations in windows phone mango application. I tried with LINQ to sql mapping.  Using Mapping tool, but realized that SQL CE doesn’t support GUI tool. Some one please suggest me a gud link or Mapping tool that will help me learn the DB Design easier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLMetal(command line tool for SQL Mapping) for mapping process in windows phone mango. For learning the basics of mango DB design, these are the best two sites. For advanced information u can go for MSDN.

1. http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/ArticleIndex
2. http://chriskoenig.net/2011/10/14/using-databases-with-mango/